# Xamarin System.Data.Sqlclient Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xamarin, sqlclient

I am new to Xamarin. I just started a test project and I want to establish SQL Server connection using VS2017 and last version of Xamarin with .net core shared project.

I can download and install `System.Data.SqlClient` with nuget, [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af2PH.png). I am also referencing it

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

without error.

But if I write a piece of code regarding SQL client even initialize connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
```

I am getting this weird error:

> (1,1): error: Dependent project Test7.csproj failed to build, using old version.

I am using fully-updated versions of all product. Which one is old? How can I clear this error?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have more than one project in your solution, including this "Test7.csproj" maybe for testing? When you installed the package in Nuget, did you include more than just the project where you're doing your development?

You may want to ensure you configured Nuget in any projects in the solution that may also need those assemblies. Here's a screenshot on what that prompt should look like, when installing the package.
https://weltersbach.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/managing-solution-nuget-packages.png

Comment: My entire project seems like this.  https://imgur.com/a/NZbCh

I think its caused of incompatiblity versions between dll and project kernel. isn't it?

Comment: Does increasing the build log verbosity provide any greater detail on your error? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx